# Marking bot Message Important or bot to mention teams

Tags: javascript, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams

Im trying to send a notification on a teams channel through bot via bot rest api ( bot has basic command to fetch some data as well ).

I am able to send normal text and/or cards.

since this will be a notification. I want to occasionally mark the message sent via bot to be "IMPORTANT" or Mention the a team

doing a POST call to api endpoint 
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations
(authorization already done and working correctly)

I am able to send just normal text activity. such as this one

```
{
    "isGroup": true,
    "activity" : {
        "type": "message", 
        "text": "Hey check out this message"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "teamsChannelId": "19:thisismyteamsid@thread.skype"
    }
}
```

sending this just makes the  text blue color and doesn't actually "mentions" the group nor mark it "important"

```
{
    "isGroup": true,
    "activity" : {
        "importance": "high",
        "type": "message", 
        "text": "Hey <at>test team</at> check out this message",
        "entities": [
            {
                "type":"mention",
                "mentioned":{
                    "id":"19:thisismyteamsid@thread.skype",
                    "name":"test team"
                },
                "text": "<at>test team</at>"
            }
        ]
    },
    "channelData": {
        "teamsChannelId": "19:thisismyteamsid@thread.skype"
    }
}
```

is there a way to do this via bot api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @mentioning teams and channels, it currently isn't possible. You can track progress [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues/139).

Regarding setting importance, as far as I can tell, it currently isn't possible. If somebody from the MS Teams team wants to chime in, that would be appreciated (I'm from the bot team).

I tested both of these extensively through Node and C# SDKs as well as the REST API. I could be missing something, but I'm fairly certain this isn't currently possible. That being said, you should be able to @mention each user after [getting a list of users on the team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context).

Comment: alright thank you, the message I'm pushing to the channel is sort of "anyone from this team needs to acknowledge it". Is there a limit to how many users you can mention on a single message?

Comment: I don't know that, myself. Hopefully one of the Teams guys can chime in. I'd imagine there's a limit of some kind to prevent spam. Worst case scenario is that you need to send multiple messages. Not ideal for your purposes, but I understand why the limitations would be put in place.

Comment: I just did some testing where I @mentioned myself 30 times and it worked fine. I'm guessing that if it allows that many entities, it also allows that many unique entities.

Comment: alright thank you very much, I was desperately trying to avoid making the message from bot long but for now I will just @mention the individual team members

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to set a message as Important.